# If quantum waves are real, how is energy conserved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation

I have been wondering the following:  If quantum waves are "real", then how can energy be conserved for a split photon upon collapse?  I am wondering if quantum objects might grab energy out of the vacuum upon collapse to solve this problem?

To be clearer, suppose a single photon wave packet is split by a beam splitter, half goes to one detector, and half to the other.  One detector detects the photon, the other nothing.  But at the detector that goes off, a full photon is detected, not half.  In fact, the photon delivers all of itself to a single electron, which leads to a detection, and much of the wave packet does not hit this electron.  If the energy is in the waves, where does the energy delivered to the electron come from?  What happens to the waves that are not detected?  This appears to indicate that quantum waves cannot be "real".

However, I am wondering if a possible solution might be in the vacuum energy?  Perhaps the electrons are allowed to grab the requisite amount of energy from the vacuum background because the photon is hitting them (only one manages to do this), and the undetected waves continue on, and are now part of the vacuum? This would lead to a picture where the electron is allowed to grab this energy when "unlocked" by a photon, otherwise it can't grab energy? Collapse then is about quantum objects grabbing a new set of waves from the background, forming a new wave packet, and presumably the one with the biggest combination of photon, original electron plus vacuum background is where collapse occurs? Is this why quantum systems are unpredictable, because we have no information about what the vacuum energy is doing  around quantum wave packets?

I am just wondering if this is possible, it seems to lead to many other questions...

Comment: there is no half of a photon

Comment: I really don't understand where this notion of splitting of quanta comes from. The entire point of quantum mechanics is that energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge can only come in quantized amounts. Every time we do a measurement we have to transfer at least one Planck unit of angular momentum somewhere. There is no way around that. This doesn't mean anything with regards to energy conservation. The energy is still there, just not in the same system.

Comment: A wave function can be split into two, or a hundred, or whatever amount of pieces.  Even for an electron that goes through a double slit, Just after leaving the slits, the electron wave function is in two spots, not in between.  A little later, it joins together. 
 Same for three slits, and so on.  The question is:  if these waves are "real" and carry energy, where do they go after detection, where does the energy come from at teh detector if alot of the waves are no where near it?

Comment: The wavefunction does not carry energy in the same sense as a classical wave, so the premise of your question is flawed. (but in an interesting way that is worth understanding)

Comment: A beam splitter just sends the entire photon one way or the other, 50/50.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have imagined a wave function as corresponding to the distribution of *the physical object* in space and time, with its mass, energy, momentum, charge, etc, all smeared out over a spatial extent. If this were the case, mass-energy-momentum would have to teleport from one place to another, violating causality and/or conservation laws.

This is not the case.

A wave function contains information about mass, energy, momentum, etc, but the wave function itself corresponds to the distribution of *probability* in space and time, not the distribution of mass-energy in space and time. Thus there is no need for mass-energy-momentum to "move" to one or the other detector: the "thing" that was elsewhere wasn't a thing at all, but the *probability of finding a something there*.

Although macroscopic probabilities are best understood in terms of a *local hidden variable model*, which has been experimentally contraindicated for quantum systems, the actual probabilities "move" the same way in probabilistic models for everyday life experiences, so they may be a useful example of what is and isn't happening.

For example, suppose Tim flips a coin every Sunday morning to decide what he will do. On heads, he goes to church. On tails, he stays home. We can describe Tim with a macroscopic probability function (not a wavefunction, this is just an analogy to show probability function collapse in everyday life).

We want to know where we will find Tim, so we describe Tim's macroscopic probability function: zero everywhere except for Church and Home, and an unknown function that integrates to 0.5 over the domain of Church and 0.5 over the domain of Home. If we visit Tim's Church and find that he is not there, Tim's macroscopic probability function collapses instantly to the Home state. If we find Tim at Church, his macroscopic probability function collapses instantly to the Church state. We have collapsed Tim's probability function, but we obviously haven't collapsed Tim.

The main differences between Tim and a photon, as regards this question, are:

1: Tim's probability distribution is a consequence of our ignorance of Tim's real current state combined with facts about our past and present interactions with Tim - namely, he has told us about his coin-flipping habit, but he hasn't told us what he flipped this morning.

On the quantum scale, the photon's probability distribution is a fact about physical reality as real as position, momentum, mass, or Tim's coin-flipping habit. It is not a consequence of our ignorance of some hidden variable local to the photon, but a real attribute of the photon-detector system.

Tim is of course made of quanta, but there are so many quantum interactions in any single measurement of Tim that our macroscopic measurements of Tim are indistinguishable from the average expectation value of all of Tim's quantum interactions.

2: We can measure Tim as often as we want without significantly changing Tim's state, because Tim is very big on the scale of the energy and momentum exchanges we need to make in order to measure him. On the scale of a single particle, any measurement of the system will significantly change the state of the particle we want to measure.

Comment: "If this were the case, mass-energy-momentum would have to teleport from one place to another, violating causality and/or conservation laws."A quantum object doesn't have to instantly transport energy from place to place if it grabs the energy it needs upon collapse from itself, the boson (photon) hitting it, and the background vacuum energy.  This is the question being asked : Instead of  energy being instantly transported from place to place, can the quantum object "grab" it from the vacuum?

Comment: @Philo236 The question is based on a false premise and can only be answered by addressing the premise. The quantum (strictly speaking, the quantum + detector system) doesn't need any extra energy to collapse its probability distribution, because the quantum's energy is not what was distributed, as I have attempted to describe above.

Answer (score -1):

> If quantum waves are "real", then how can energy be conserved for a split photon upon collapse?

For a free electron with mass $m$, the Schrödinger equation would be
$$\Psi_{k} (z,t)\propto e^{[-i(\frac{E(k)}{\hslash } -kz)]}=e^{-i[\omega (k)t+kz]}$$

where $$E(t)=\frac{\hslash^{2} k^{2}}{2m_{e}}$$ and the frequency would be $\omega (k)=\frac{E(k)}{\hslash }$. This is for a time dependent quantum mechanical system and it evolves over time, energy depends on $E(t)=\frac{\hslash^{2} k^{2}}{2m_{e}}$. For this system, it can be observed that the energy will change with time accordingly to the relation. It does not 'break' into pieces. It should be noted that locality in quantum mechanics is simply an assumption. It causes more problems than answers hence we disregard it.

> To be clearer, suppose a single photon wave packet is split by a beam splitter, half goes to one detector, and half to the other. One detector detects the photon, the other nothing. But at the detector that goes off, a full photon is detected, not half. In fact, the photon delivers all of itself to a single electron, which leads to a detection, and much of the wave packet does not hit this electron. If the energy is in the waves, where does the energy delivered to the electron come from? What happens to the waves that are not detected? This appears to indicate that quantum waves cannot be "real".

The electron goes through both of the slits, however when forced to observe the mentioned wave function collapses. It does not separate into two and the other missing piece goes to somewhere else. Because of that occurrence, the energy perseverance is no issue.

For the double slit experiment, you can use exponential waves such as $$\psi_{s} (x)\propto e^{ik\sqrt{(x-5/2} +z^{2}_{0}}+e^{ik\sqrt{(x+5/2} +z^{2}_{0}}$$ so by using approximate formulas for distance, it would give us $$\psi_{s} (x)\propto e^{i\alpha }[e^{ik\left( 5x/2z_{0}\right)  }+e^{-ik\left( 5x/2z_{0}\right)  }]$$ I assume here might be your interpretation of 'real quantum waves' or 'if real' come to play. These formulas are simply a mathematical tool and have no real life correspondence unless you take the modulus squared of the term with Born's rule. Then it becomes a probability density and will have a meaning. When you observe the wave, the function collapses 'in accordance of the Copenhagen interpretation' and you observe the particle.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a 'vacuum energy'? Do you mean a pervasive background energy that permeates space?